# Dependency injection unit testing of type erasured code

Tags: c++, boost

In this talk Boris Schäling presented how to create factory system of different kind of connections (tcp vs udp) without runtime polymorphism. He used Boost Type Erasure: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vo9F35G-Rfk&t=2706s
The concept is very interesting, the code looks great. See below:

```
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/concept_check.hpp>
#include <boost/type_erasure/any.hpp>
#include <boost/type_erasure/member.hpp>
#include <boost/type_erasure/free.hpp>
#include <boost/type_erasure/builtin.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/vector.hpp>
using namespace std;

BOOST_TYPE_ERASURE_MEMBER((has_send), send)

using Connection = boost::type_erasure::any<
                        boost::mpl::vector<
                        has_send<void(const char*)>,
                        boost::type_erasure::copy_constructible<>>>;

BOOST_TYPE_ERASURE_MEMBER((has_make), make)

using ConnectionFactory = boost::type_erasure::any<
                        boost::mpl::vector<
                        has_make<Connection()>,
                        boost::type_erasure::copy_constructible<>,
                        boost::type_erasure::relaxed>>;

struct TcpConnection
{
    void send(const char* s) { cout << s << endl; }
};

struct UdpConnection
{
    void send(const char* s) { cout << s << endl; }
};

struct TcpConnectionFactory
{
    TcpConnection make() { return TcpConnection(); }
};

struct UdpConnectionFactory
{
    UdpConnection make() { return UdpConnection(); }
};

template <class ConnFactory>
void send(ConnFactory& cf)
{
    Connection conn = cf.make();
    conn.send("hello");
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    ConnectionFactory cf;
    if (argc > 1 && argv[1] == "tcp"s)
        cf = TcpConnectionFactory();
    else
        cf = UdpConnectionFactory();

    send(cf);
}
```

https://wandbox.org/permlink/DoLQEwERuFpq5cEQ

But I started wondering: **How would you test this code?** Traditionally you apply some kind of dependency injection so that you can inject stubs or mocks into the real code and test how they are called in the test code. But in this kind of code, using Boost Type Erasure, it seems rather hard.

I know this is a very general question, but...: how would you unit test this code? Is it possible?

Comment: Which code: `send`?  How is that hard to test?  As an aside, `send` can take a fixed type instead of a template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But I started wondering: How would you test this code?

Like any other code. In fact, your main could be a test.

> Traditionally you apply some kind of dependency injection so that you can inject stubs or mocks into the real code and test how they are called in the test code.

Not necessarily. Often over-stubbing/mocking leads to testing the mocks instead of your code.

> But in this kind of code, using Boost Type Erasure, it seems rather hard.

How so? Erasure makes things easier, since all you have to mock is a "duck type" interface (the concept).

Always think about what you need to test, and how you'll be satisfied that it works.

Demo:

```
struct MockConnectionFactory {
    std::ostream& _sensor;

    auto make() {
        struct {
            std::ostream& _sensor;
            void send(const char *s) { _sensor << s << '\n'; }
        } x {_sensor};
        return x;
    }
};
```

Test:

```
std::stringstream buffer;

ConnectionFactory cf = MockConnectionFactory{ buffer };
auto c = cf.make();
CHECK_EQUAL("", buffer.str());

c.send("this should be received");
CHECK_EQUAL("this should be received\n", buffer.str());
```

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fa8f903973164ade)</kbd>**

Comment: Thank you, but... your test tests something different. What I wanted to achieve was to test my main function (say it is my whole program and I I just want to make sure that if I run it with "tcp" option it creates a TcpConnection and sends texts using this tcp connection, etc.). Your test code doesn't utilize any of the classes that exists in the project (Connection, ConnectionFactory, TCPConnection, UDPConnection). That is really not what I wanted to achieve, sorry.

Comment: lol. "Your test tests something different". No, I made up a test because you didn't specify anything at all. Like I said _"Always think about what you need to test, and how you'll be satisfied that it works."_ Feel free to disregard the example.

Comment: I am trying to figure out how to make sure my project gets high (and of good quality) test coverage.

Comment: You do that by actually testing stuff, not by worrying about technicalities. If you can't write the code for the test, you can't write the code for the production.

Comment: Ok, so see my previous comment. I would like to make sure that I have high test coverage.

Comment: What I would like to achieve is to write a test in which I provide some mock of a Connection class, and if I run the tests with tcp option, my mock's 'send' method gets called with string "hello". Using traditional approach with runtime polymorphism I was able to do this. But in this code I just don't know how to.

Comment: My code already shows pretty much *exactly* that. The crux is, you create the mock. It's very easy due to the type-erasure

Comment: I think I got what you meant.

Comment: Thanks. Your example was very helpful.

Comment: Cheers! Oh, in case you are looking for some hints on how to iterate lists of types: you can [use plain variadics](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/336f0fe5092990ae) or e.g. [something like Boost MPL or Fusion](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/63ff679e76c45cfd)

Comment: One more question: this is testing of the global function 'send'. It is great. But if I also want to test what happens before, in the main function? Is it possible to write a unit test for my main function to verify that if in the arguments I pass "tcp" then the object of my TcpConnection factory is passed to my 'send' function, and otherwise the object of my UdpConnection factory is passed there? I guess I would have to mock somehow the 'send' function itself, using e.g. a library like PreMock or CMock. But how to handle the argument? If I used pointers to some base class it would be feasible

Comment: What. Are. You. Testing? If you're testing the full program (including main), just... run the program :)
It seems a bit as if you are worried that your program wouldn't launch, for magical reasons, even if all your unit tests pass. If so, that's just a logic error of the most simple variation: it'll be immediately obvious, as wil be the fix.

Seriously, don't glorify coverage or tests in general. Far more important to have clean design, no ActionAtADistance, no GodClasses or other hidden GlobalStateAntiPatterns etc. If you do, unit tests and integration tests suffice.

Comment: In my opinion you should test as much as you can. The main function contains some logic. In this case there's very little of it, but still. What if it grows in time and you don't test this logic, and after 2 years a new developer comes and changes something. He forgets that he should run manually the program with all the options possible to verify he didn't break anything. He pushes the changes and they go to production. You have a major failure on production.

Comment: Nobody stops you (integration, deployment) testing your application. Just don't expect a lot of test doctrine magic to **help** in that department. Because soon enough, things seem to work in test, and you still have major failure in production.

Comment: I know that tests cannot help 100%, but I think they can find many errors. When code gets bigger and bigger tests also are some kind of documentation of what the author thought about how this code should work.